# Add inline CSS to woocommerce product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I add inline CSS styles to product list loop in WooCommerce? I need to do it because I want to put there variables from Advanced Custom Fields, and let user to change border, and background color of product list loop. Below some code from product loop:

```
<li class="product-category product first">
```

And I want o change it to:

```
<li class="product-category product first" style="ACF_VARIABLE_HERE">
```

But I can't make changes inside INCLUDES catalog php files. I don't want to loose anything during WP update. Product loop is inside this catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good way would be to create a child theme andthen modify your page template in the child theme to add your ACF variable to the product loop.

Refer https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/ on how to setup a child theme in woocommerce.

Comment: I made from basics my own WP template, I not using child-theme. All pages working on template-parts folder with my own PHP code. Also I have there WooCommerce template files to ovverride them. I need to make changes in "includes" catalog php files, but it is not possible to ovverride this catalog. Only option is adding filters/functions in functions.php file but I don't know how to force adding inline css using functions.php file.